# How split Value Complex data in openmrs and spring?

Tags: java, spring, openmrs

I am facing problem to split given string with | operator but its work with other special glue .
Here is my data: **txt file |f3558100-f384-43a1-847e-8cafc747156b**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also faced same problem while spiting string with **| operator**.
but **|** operator is exception case in java while spiting.
You go like this it will be work for you because same problem i faced in opemmrs **ValueComplex**  string split.

```
String valueData = obs1.getValueComplex();
String[] complexDataUuid = valueData.split("\\|");
String uuid = complexDataUuid[1];
```

So, You can get **uuid** in **complexDataUuid[1]**